# Replace all the occurences of JS with an empty line using sed

Tags: html, regex, linux, shell, sed

I have arounf 50 html files and I have to replace the integrity and sha part with the empty lines

in all the html files we can find common JS with

```
<script crossorigin='anonymous' integrity='sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q' src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js'></script>
```

I need to replace this with just the

```
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js'></script>
```

I tried `sed` command with

```
sed -i -e 's|<script crossorigin='anonymous' integrity='sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q' src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js'></script>|<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js'></script>|g' *.html
```

It did not replace any of that

Comment: There are lots of edge cases with HTML that are hard to parse using just regular expressions. Would you be open to a Python script using the BeautifulSoup parser?

Comment: Yeah sure , but I managed to do it in sed command and it worked out well,

Comment: You can answer your own question then for the sake of future readers. :-)

Answer (score 0):

as simple as below with the given string and considering everything to be removed between first and last spaces, and no spaces in the URL string, so here you go:

```
< test.txt sed 's/ .* / /'
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js'></script>
```

while test.txt contains the original string.

Answer (score -1):

I finally managed to figure this out and managed to replace the js in all my html files

````
sed -i -e "s|<script crossorigin='anonymous' integrity='sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q' src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js'></script>|<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js'></script>|" *.html ```
````